# $http.post in angular not firing webapi controller method with form data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have some strange issue with AngularJS and WebAPi controller method.

**Issue Details:** 
I have an controller webapi method which will have UserName, Email and Password as model class. When I try to post the data to the webapi method, I always end up in response as error. The Webapi method in controller is not fired when data is entered in form but if I don't fill any data in the form and just click on the submit button, webapi method is fired(model data is empty as no data filled in form).

Question is why is this happening for all post method. Please note I did not get any error in script(no error in console window)

I have been struggling on this for many days and finally thought to post here to get help on this.

I tried this with jquery ajax to post the same data to webapi but facing same issue (method fired only when I don't enter any data in the form).

```
//html code

  <div class="form-horizontal">
            <hr />

            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">User name</asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" id="UserName" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required="" data-ng-model="userName" placeholder="User Name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Email</asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="email" id="Email" class="form-control" maxlength="256" required="" data-ng-model="email" placeholder="Email Id" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="password" id="Password" class="form-control" maxlength="256" required="" data-ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Confirm password</asp:Label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="password" id="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" maxlength="256" required="" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-ng-model="confirmPassword" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Register" Text="Register" CssClass="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="CreateAccount()" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



//controller code
myApp.controller('AccountController', function ($scope, account) {

    var onUserRegisterComplete = function (response) {
        $scope.success = "success";
        alert(response.data);
        $scope.registerMessage = response.data;
    };

    var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.error = "Could not fetch details.";
    };

   $scope.CreateAccount = function () {
        alert("CreateAccount trigged");
        var registerUser = { UserName: $scope.userName, Email: $scope.email, Password: $scope.password, ConfirmPassword: $scope.confirmPassword };
       account.registerUser(registerUser).then(onUserRegisterComplete, onError);
   };


    $scope.userName = "";
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.password = "";
    $scope.confirmPassword = "";
});


//angularjs service code

myApp.service('account', function ($http) {

    var registerUser = function (userRegister) {
        var url = "http://localhost:1443/api/account/userregister";

        var data = JSON.stringify(userRegister);

        return $http.post(
            url,
            data,
            {
                headers:
                {
                    "Content-Type":
                        "application/json"
                }
            }
        ).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
    };


    return {
        registerUser: registerUser
    };

});


//webapi method

 [Route("api/account/userregister")]
        public IHttpActionResult PostRegisterUser([FromBody]RegisterViewModel registerData)
        {
           //do some registration action
            return Ok("ok");
        }
```

please let me know if I have missed to mention something. Thanks

Comment: Why JSON.stringify the data? Thats already on JSON format. And you should be able to get the data without the FromBody

Comment: First concern is about webapi method not fired, I tried removing the [FromBody] and hit the login button with data, surprisingly controller method fired with data then from second time it is not fired again, it is fired if i dont fill form controls. I found these warning in console.

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.browserLink:37 Setting 'XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials' for synchronous requests is deprecated.